# SSAS Tabular Extended Events Session Randomly Deleted

Tags: logging, ssas, tabular, extended-events

SSAS Instance: 1200
Version: 13.2.5830.85

Hi

I created an Extended Event on the Instance to minimally capture usage of our Tabular cubes (this blog was my guide [https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4548/using-extended-events-to-monitor-dax-queries-for-ssas-tabular-databases/#:~:text=%20Solution%20%201%20Step%201%3A%20Open%20SSMS,as%20shown%20below.%20Execute%20this%20script...%20More%20](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4548/using-extended-events-to-monitor-dax-queries-for-ssas-tabular-databases/#:%7E:text=%20Solution%20%201%20Step%201%3A%20Open%20SSMS,as%20shown%20below.%20Execute%20this%20script...%20More%20)).

This all works well for several weeks and then it suddenly disappears.  The XEL file remains.

I've asked the DBA's if they're running any scripts that could remove this, they said no.

The file has rollover and plenty of space.

I cannot find any literature that says it has a time limit.

So my question is what are the possible reasons (bar manually deleting or via script) for the trace to be deleted?

Does a server reboot remove it?

Also any suggestions as to working around this issue (not ASTrace, as it's not allowed) would be very welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Update, the server's were rebooted.  But i'd still like to hear suggestion as to how work round this or a better solution altogether.

Answer (score 1):

After running select * from $System.DISCOVER_TRACES is discovered a setting called AutoRestart.  Never heard of it before.  Did some digging and found this article http://byobi.com/2016/08/analysis-services-extended-events-autorestart-option/ .  Adding true resolved the issue.  hope this helps someone in the future

Comment: Have been wondering why my Extended Events are disappearing ! Now, I know. Thanks for sharing